# docker-compose volumes database data auto deletes

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-compose

So i have got a question . I have got a project with multi containerized docker containers using docker-compose, .net5.0

SO i'm using a database container aswell the mssql 2019 latest.
Everytime i restart my comuter or my project or docker for desktop my containers get deleted which in this case will also delete my database container and delete it's data.

So i decided to attach my database (mdf file) (data folder) to a volume.

[image: Picutre]

This volume works i have got a local database folder with my database inside, however I still have the same problem after a computer restart my database is empty all my data is being deleted.

How can I prevent this from being deleted.
Since its a small project i intend to keep my database in container for production rather than an external database on a vm or something.

Comment: What OS do you use? macOS, Windows, or Linux?

Comment: i use windows as host os my containers are linux